# ActiveMQ JMS Topic - delete old messages

Tags: activemq-classic, purge, jms-topic

Is there a way to monitor messages in ActiveMQ JMS topic and most importantly delete older messages, e.g. delete messages older than a month ago.

I am using Apache Camel to build ActiveMQ Connection and JMS topics.

Answer (score 1):

There is a header within sent JMS messages called time to live, which when surpassed will remove the messages from the queue.

It is possible to achieve the same affects at the broker level.

Further information can be found here http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html